# Parse GET parameters

Tags: python, rest, urllib, argparse, url-parameters

I have an `REST API` where the url looks like this:

```
class RRervice(pyrestful.rest.RestHandler):
      @get('/Indicator/{rparms}')
      def RR(self, rparms):

        print(rparms)       
        
        ...
```

So when this codes executes on this URL:

```
http://ip:3000/Indicator/thresh=.8&symbol=AAPL
```

The `print` I get what I am supposed to get:

```
thresh=.8&symbol=AAPL
```

My question is, is there an API that ensures that certain parameters must exist, and if so, what is the best way to parse them? I have seen `urllib`, or maybe even `argparse`. I guess I am looking for the right way to do this. I know I can hack it by `split`, but that just solves getting what was typed in the URL, not the correctness of the URL parameters.

Comment: What framework does `get` come from? That should be responsible for defining endpoints with required parameters, and handling errors when those are missing.

Comment: Use a validation library like [pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic).

Comment: The framework is pyrestful

Comment: that's not a standard url. You should have `?` between the path and the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're already receiving the exact part of the URL that corresponds to the querystring without the question mark, if you want to parse it natively (i.e. without using the framework that you're using), you can use `parse_qs` from urllib.parse:

```py
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

...

class RRervice(pyrestful.rest.RestHandler):
      @get('/Indicator/{rparms}')
      def RR(self, rparms):
            pparams = parse_qs(rparms)
            print(pparams.get("thresh"))       
            print(pparams.get("symbol"))       
        ...
```

In order to enforce it, you can check whether the `pparams.get(param_name)` is None, like so:

```py
if(pparams.get("thresh") is None):
   "Return your error to the client somehow"
```